# Do we need to use separate IP ?

Tags: network, pci-dss

I want to open and forward SSH port to one of our internal computers.

Problem is - it will use the same IP address as PCI-DSS environment (where the HTTPS payment gatway is running)

Basically firewall will forward port 22 to ssh server, port 443 to PCI-DSS environment

Is it compliant with PCI-DSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the firewall is outside of what constitutes your "PCI-DSS environment" then this is mere routing. To say things bluntly, all machines share the same Internet. PCI-DSS will rely on some sort of boundary which delimits what is *inside* (and in scope of PCI-DSS), and the rest of the World. The latter includes the firewall, the SSH server...

In particular, the SSL layer makes a tunnel which ensures protection for data in transit between the SSL (HTTPS) client and the server, and that protection holds against all other machines in-between, *including* the firewall.

It all boils down to this: if your PCI-DSS compliance does not depend on the properties of the firewall (i.e. you would still comply with PCI-DSS if the firewall was removed, and your servers placed directly in contact with the Internet), then the firewall can do whatever it pleases, including forwarding SSH connections to some other server, without impacting PCI-DSS compliance.

Comment: in my case no firewall = no internet at all. firewall separates two networks (pci-dss env. and office network).

Comment: I hate to disagree but there are a lot of 'firewalls' that actually have level 7 inspection capability, especially for HTTPS. If that's the case and and the decrypted cardholder data is in memory the firewall is in scope. That is an easy point for folks to get confused on and it took a couple reads to get that from your post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe that as long as you isolate the SSH system from the payment gateway you are fine.  The fact they are using the same IP outside doesn't matter since port forwarding is simply directing the traffic to two separate networks.  I believe the network separation is the important part and port routing doesn't directly impact that.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your SSH Server is complient:

- no root access to SSH
- dont use the default port of ssh (22)
- public key auth only
- no shared accounts.

And you can use source-network/IP restrictions (SSH only reachable from 172.16.x.y).

But 100% safe to go, speak with your auditor.